# SharedSizeGroup in ListView.ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, layout, controls, grid

I have this scenario where I want to share the column size among all the ListViewItems, and I'm using SharedSizeGroup on the column definitions but it doesn't work:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="C" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0" Text="{Binding Text1}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0" Text="{Binding Text2}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,0" Text="{Binding Text3}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I know a possible solution is using a GridView as the ListView.View, but there's a few design issues that prevent us from doing this. Is there any other way I can achieve sharing the column widths?

This is what I want to achieve (the columns with the same colors should share width):

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The only thing that is missing is the scope i think, add [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope.aspx)`="True"` to the `ListView` attributes.

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes to set your answer as accepted. Will do so ASAP.